Retrieving reasons for all apt kept back packages?
Since forever, I've been getting pissed off when I get something like this:
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  arandr lxinput raspberrypi-ui-mods raspi-utils

The first question that pops into my mind when I see this is "WHY are these packages kept back?" and then I have to waste hours by reading documentation and trying commands until I figure that out.
"The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it? explains that there are in general 3 reasons for "kept back" packages:


It is marked as held back
apt detects a dependency change
Phased updates


So is there some command or option that would give me an output like
$ pseudo-apt-reason-why-kept-back
arandr - kept back due to: marked as held back
lxinput - kept back due to: dependency change
raspberrypi-ui-mods - kept back due to: phased updates
raspi-utils - kept back due to: phased updates


The top answer there also lists commands for each reason to show the corresponding packages. There is no single command for all three.

Thanks @muru - I was hoping there was something out there I could use, so I don't have to go through those commands manually ...
